# Ayuda con consulta SQL (varios registros del mismo campo)

Tags: mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, sql

Espero explicarme bien y que puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano, la situación es la siguiente:

Estoy desarrollando un sistema que diagnostica fallas de computadoras, el cual funcionará de la siguiente manera, el usuario va a seleccionar varios síntomas y de acuerdo a esos síntomas el sistema le dirá que falla tiene (o puede tener) su pc, para eso tengo 3 tablas, la tabla FALLA la tabla SÍNTOMAS y una que llamé SÍNTOMA_FALLA la cual es el enlace de las 2 anteriores ya que lo manejo como una relación muchos a muchos (una falla puede tener varios síntomas y un síntoma a su vez puede pertenecer a varias fallas),  la cuestión es que necesito obtener la falla que coincida con los síntomas enviados por el usuario; algo asi mas o menos:

> la tabla FALLA tiene 2 campos: ID, DESCRIPCION
>
> la tabla sintomas tiene tambien: ID, DESCRIPCION
>
> la tabla SINTOMA-FALLA tiene: ID, FALLA, SINTOMA

Supongamos que el usuario selecciona los sintomas: "la pc no arranca (cuyo id es 2)" y "Se escuchan pitidos anormales (id 4)",

Intenté algo asi:

```
Select f.descripcion as falla, s.descripcion as sintoma 
from sintoma_falla sf 
inner join falla f 
     on f.id=sf.falla 
inner join sintoma s 
      on s.id=sf.sintoma 
WHERE sf.sintoma=2 and sf.sintoma=4
```

Pero no funciona, El resultado que quiero es: el nombre de la falla que coincida con los todos síntomas seleccionados.

de nuevo gracias y espero que puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas simple para lo que quieres es comprobar para cada falla si existe una relacion con sintoma_falla tanto para valor 2 como para valor 4.

```
SELECT f.descripcion 
FROM falla f
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM sintoma_falla sf
              WHERE sf.falla = f.id
              AND sf.sintoma = 2)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM sintoma_falla sf
              WHERE sf.falla = f.id
              AND sf.sintoma = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Otro modo de conserguirlo es con joins contando aquellos resultados que tienen el número de síntomas buscado.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE FALLA (
  ID INT,
  DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(50)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO FALLA (ID, DESCRIPCION) VALUES (1, "Fallo 1");
INSERT INTO FALLA (ID, DESCRIPCION) VALUES (2, "Fallo 2");

CREATE TABLE SINTOMA  (
  ID INT,
  DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(50)
)DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO SINTOMA (ID, DESCRIPCION) VALUES (1, "Síntoma 1");
INSERT INTO SINTOMA (ID, DESCRIPCION) VALUES (2, "Síntoma 2");

CREATE TABLE FALLASINTOMA  (
  IDF INT,
  IDS INT
);
INSERT INTO FALLASINTOMA (IDF, IDS) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO FALLASINTOMA (IDF, IDS) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO FALLASINTOMA (IDF, IDS) VALUES (2, 2);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, F.DESCRIPCION
FROM FALLA F
INNER JOIN FALLASINTOMA FS ON FS.IDF=F.ID
LEFT JOIN SINTOMA S1 ON FS.IDS=S1.ID AND S1.ID=1
LEFT JOIN SINTOMA S2 ON FS.IDS=S2.ID AND S2.ID=2    
GROUP BY F.DESCRIPCION HAVING TOTAL=2;
```

| TOTAL | DESCRIPCION |

| 2     | Fallo 1     |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Yo estoy trabajando del lado de Hana Studio y muy a menudo me suelo topar con problemas de este tipo lo que se recomienda en este caso es una consulta integral, que conlleve los datos de los (Síntomas) que pueda tener o suceder.

Lo que te recomiendo de gran manera es esto.

```
SELECT 
F.descripcion AS "falla",
S.descripcion AS "sintoma" 
FROM sintoma_falla sf 
INNER JOIN falla F ON F.id=SF.falla 
INNER JOIN sintoma S ON S.id=SF.sintoma 
WHERE SF.sintoma IN ('2','4')
```

Aclaro que de igual manera en el WHERE podrías poner los demás síntomas si deseas una consulta general o dejarlo por varias consultas con diferentes síntomas.

Comment: Esto no cumple lo que pide el usuario. `sintoma` tiene que valer `2 y 4` no `2 o 4`

Comment: @JDev aclaro la justificación del Where en el se resalta dentro de la consulta los campos que cumplen para estar dentro de ella te explico, como tu dices el valor tiene que valer 2 y 4 digamos una consulta practica para ambos campos ahora en where se delimita los valores de SF.sintoma que podra tener la Condición IN seria como SF.sintoma y que contenga 2 y 4 no solo 1 de ellos si no que ambos campos.

Comment: No, tu ´where´ no te trae solo aquellos que tengan `2 y 4` a la vez, te puede traer perfectamente los que solo contengan 2 pero no 4 y eso no es lo que pide el usuario.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, pero esto ya lo había intentado, y el resultado era parecido pero no exacto a lo que necesito. Igual gracias por tu aporte